# How to find duplicate values in one column and different values on other column on same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select all rows who have same **SrlNbr** value and different **Type** in same table.
I have try many ways but did not work. Please help.

Example I want to list with ID:1,2, 5,6 and not 3,4

[image]

Comment: ,please look at the simple solution what i have given below and let me know if still you have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.SrlNbr = t.SrlNbr and t2.type <> t.type
             );
```

If you just want `srlnbr`s with different types, then aggregation is convenient:

```
select srlnbr
from t
group by srlnbr
having min(type) <> max(type);
```

Comment: I need something like that SELECT ID, SrlNbr, type, desc WHERE SrlNbr are same and have different Type FROM Table

Comment: @Saketo . . . That is what the first query does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Condition should be t2.type <> t.type in first query for correct result

Answer (score 4):

I have simple solution for your problem , just put your table name at the place **Your_table**.

Please check the query below..

```
SELECT a.ID
    ,a.SrlNbr
    ,a.Type
    ,a.[Desc]
FROM Your_Table AS a
INNER JOIN Your_Table AS b ON a.SrlNbr = b.SrlNbr
WHERE a.Type != b.Type
```

Comment: I got some results but they are multiply by 5 in my selected rows

Comment: I don't think so ,it's a simple join it will reflect all the matching records only,as per your problem..